# Does having multiple <HTML> element tags on one page cause problems

Tags: html, w3c, dtd

I cam accross this specific situation today. On a client's website, the pages had multiple  tags, some even with conflicting Doctypes:
Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>....</head></body>...</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>....</head></body>...</body>
</html>
```

All this within the same page.

Will this cause any issues, if so which ones ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem that this will cause is that it is invalid HTML and it is indeterminate how the content will be rendered.

Comment: This is the best that can be said because each browser behaves differently.

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone knew of specific issues with this type of code. The development of the site was outsourced and this is the code I have to deal with to add analytics. If the javascript breaks, or doesnt run on some browsers then the analytics data is pretty flawed.

Comment: @vinnybuzz: your last sentence is correct. Use this as the argument to have the code fixed before you proceed. Whoever coded this is ripping you off.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the standard "web" answer, but basically it depends on how the browser handles it. It's obviously not standards-compliant HTML so it would be good to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

apart from that it is plain ugly and non-standard,
it has surely caused browser hickups in browser before, i dont know how the common browsers behave today.

i recall the day when one experimented with multiple body tags with different bgcolors to create a blinking background effect :)